# Eliminate duplicate data from table sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table containing with bunch of duplicate data.
for example

```
ID           Visited URL

1             google.com
1             facebook.com
1             google.com
1             facebook.com
2             google.com
2             google.com
```

I need to avoid these duplicate rows and get unique rows as follows.

```
ID           Visited URL

1            google.com
1            facebook.com
2            google.com
```

How could I do that? any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use either of the following

```
 Select ID,VisitedURL from tablename group by ID,VisitedURL
```

or

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ID,VisitedURL from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

What about 
`SELECT DISTINCT ID, Visited URL
FROM YOUR TABLE..`

It will only gives you non duplicated rows;